# Installing specific version of docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I need instructions on how to install a specific version of docker (docker-engine) and docker-compose.

Docker version must be 1.11.2.

Docker-compose version must be 1.8.1.

I've googled and when I trying to install one of them, e.g. docker 1.11.2, then docker compose. And after this docker updating to latest version

Comment: follow this link as it is having more comprehensive answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839028/how-to-upgrade-docker-compose-to-latest-version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Docker Debian/Ubuntu repository is at https://apt.dockerproject.org/. You can download individual deb packages under the directory https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/pool/main/d/docker-engine/ for quite a few older versions.

The Docker Compose releases are provided by the github repo at: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases