# How to upgrade docker-compose to latest version

Tags: docker-compose, debian-based

I have installed docker-compose using the command

`sudo apt install docker-compose`

It installed docker-compose version 1.8.0 and build unknown

I need the latest version of docker-compose or at least a version of 1.9.0

Can anyone please let me know what approach I should take to upgrade it or uninstall and re-install the latest version.

I have checked the docker website and can see that they are recommending this to install the latest version'

`sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

But before that, I have to uninstall the present version, which can be done using the command

`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

but this can be used only when the installation was done using curl. I am not sure if the installation was done by curl as I have used

`sudo apt install docker-compose`

Please let me know what should I do now to uninstall and re-install the docker-compose.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

First, *remove the old version*:

If installed via **apt-get**

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-compose
```

If installed via **curl**

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

If installed via **pip**

```
pip uninstall docker-compose
```

Then *find the newest version* on [the release page at GitHub](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) or by curling the API and extracting the version from the response using `grep` or `jq` (thanks to [dragon788](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3794873/dragon788), [frbl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071450/frbl), and [Saber Hayati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392333/saber-hayati) for these improvements):

```
# curl + grep
VERSION=$(curl --silent https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | grep -Po '"tag_name": "\K.*\d')

# curl + jq
VERSION=$(curl --silent https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | jq .name -r)
```

Finally, *download* to your favorite $PATH-accessible location and set permissions:

```
DESTINATION=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o $DESTINATION
sudo chmod 755 $DESTINATION
```

Comment: Can you give some details about how it's not working?

Comment: try updating path in /usr/local/bin/docker-compose and then run `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose`

Comment: No need to move the file.  The `/usr/local/bin` path should be in `$PATH` already. Just `chmod` in place. Answer updated to reflect this.

Comment: You probably want to do `sudo chmod 755 $DESTINATION` instead of just `+x`

Comment: Neo, good catch. I typically just adjust perms to my need in case other things have set things how they need it.  But here we are downloading a fresh file. Setting all perms makes sense.

Comment: I follow this solution and my working doker-compose stops working and give an error like "usr/local/bin/docker-compose: 1: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: Not: not found"

Comment: @ChiragKalal Check that the binary is in that location with the proper permissions.

Comment: I don't know what was the issue but I reinstall it and it works fine.

Comment: Could the owner please update his answer? for most of us the path is incorrect, besides i already did it with the right path ^^

Comment: @Rebar Can you please be more specific about what you want the path updated to? `/usr/local/bin` is a pretty standard place to put global binaries not managed by the packaging system. The answer also mentions specifying "your favorite $PATH-accessible location" which indicates adjusting if your `$PATH` is different.

Comment: If you don't want to install `jq` to get the latest version:
```VERSION=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | grep -Po '"tag_name": "\K.*\d')```

Comment: @SaberHayati thanks, included this in the answer in case they don't have jq.

Comment: @ChiragKalal if you get an error like  `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: Not: not found` it's probably because like me, you did `sudo su` before the last step (unnecessarily) and the subshell created doesn't have the $VERSION variable you just made

Comment: There is a typo in the line of Curl command, there is the correct:
`sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$\{VERSION\}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o $DESTINATION`

Comment: I don't see why you would need to escape the braces, is anyone else having an issue with them?

Comment: I added tab completions per https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/ but not sure why they refer to version 1.29.2 in the URL - when I tried to most recent $VERSION it didn't work though so my tab completion might be for an older version

Comment: I mean you should just: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/ :D

Comment: I've used DESTINATION=/usr/bin/docker-compose

Comment: and this is the curl command people with zsh:

sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o $DESTINATION

Comment: I had to remove the previous installation by
which docker-compose
and then rm [path of docker compose from the previous result]

Answer (score 73):

With the release of Docker-Compose v2, which was rewritten in Go, the original mentioned approch doesn't work anymore (thanks [Denilson Sá Maia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124946/denilson-s%c3%a1-maia) for pointing that out). If you have Docker Desktop, `docker-compose` command should work out-of-the-box. If you're on Linux, have a look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/#install-using-the-repository, which for Ubuntu/Debian means:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
```

### Working until July 2023

The easiest way to have a permanent and sustainable solution for the Docker Compose installation and the way to upgrade it, is to just use the [package manager pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) with:

```
pip install docker-compose
```

I was searching for a good solution for the ugly "how to upgrade to the latest version number"-problem, which appeared after you´ve read the official docs - and just found it occasionally - just have a look at the [docker-compose pip package](https://pypi.org/project/docker-compose/) - it should reflect (mostly) the current number of the [latest released Docker Compose version](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases).

A package manager is always the best solution if it comes to managing software installations! So you just abstract from handling the versions on your own.

Comment: +1 great answer. Before: I had docker-compose version: docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471 So to upgrade to latest non-RC version, I found this to work in order to upgrade: 1) `apt install python-pip` to install PIP then  `pip install docker-compose` to install the latest and then to check the version: `docker-compose --version` which gave me: docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad0

Comment: `pip install docker-compose` was giving me "Requirement already satisfied: docker-compose" so I had to do `apt-get purge docker-compose` and `hash -d docker-compose` then `pip install docker-compose` to get docker-compose 1.24 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: After installing docker-compose by pip, I encountered this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Context'`

Comment: So, to deal with this error, I reinstall `docker` package by `pip`

Comment: No longer works for docker-compose  v2+

Comment: Docker compose V2 was rewritten from Python to Go, and thus this answer here is obsolete and no longer works.

Comment: You're right, updated accordingly.

Answer (score 34):

If you tried `sudo apt-get remove docker-compose` and get `E: Unable to locate package docker-compose`, try this method :

**This command must return a result, in order to check it is installed here :**

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**Remove the old version :**

```
sudo rm -rf docker-compose
```

**Download the last version** (check official repo : [docker/compose/releases](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases)) :

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

(*replace 1.24.0 if needed*)

**Finally, apply executable permissions to the binary:**

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**Check version :**

```
docker-compose -v
```

Comment: After doing this, I get this error - bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory

Comment: Add "v" before version number example : sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.12.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Comment: If you got error like `bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory` , just run `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose`, then you'll resolve this issue.

Comment: Newer versions: `sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.2.3/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/bin/docker-compose`

Answer (score 24):

If the above methods aren't working for you, then refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40554985

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" > ./docker-compose
sudo mv ./docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20350634)

Comment: @Luuklag Updated the answer. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: It seems to be extremely slow option

Comment: This is by far the best solution, just needed to change the version number and I was able to update docker-compose in under a minute! With regards to the comment made by @TeoTN - this isn't a slow option at all, it's just dependent on your internet speed as it downloads the docker-compose binary directly.

Comment: Lol, maybe the mirrors servers were upgraded withing the last three years, idk. I was on 300Mbps back then so probably the issue wasn't on my side.

Comment: Add "v" before version number example : sudo curl -L "github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.12.0/… -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Answer (score 21):

Based on @eric-johnson's answer, I'm currently using this in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
compose_version=$(curl https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | jq .name -r)
output='/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$compose_version/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o $output
chmod +x $output
echo $(docker-compose --version)
```

it grabs the latest version from the GitHub api.

Comment: I encountered with an error in 4th line: `zsh: parse error near `)'`

Comment: just tested it out here, but it seems to work fine (debian 10 with zsh). You sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Try double quoting the URLs as sometimes the shell can get a bit grabby.

Comment: Not necessary to `echo $(docker-compose --version)`, doing `docker-compose --version` gives a simple result.

Answer (score 21):

Here is another oneliner to install the latest version of docker-compose using  curl and sed.

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/`curl -fsSLI -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest | sed 's#.*tag/##g' && echo`/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer!
The most simple/ short and useful solution!

Comment: After doing this, I get this error - bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory

Comment: @martinho I had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04, I had to logout and login in order to get it working.

Comment: ✅ This should be the correct answer as it is small and works like charm! A great oneliner.

Answer (score 19):

**Simple Solution to update docker-compose**

This will remove the existing binary of docker-compose and install a new version.

```
sudo cd /usr/local/bin && sudo rm -rf docker-compose
sudo curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.24.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x docker-compose
```

> for the latest version visit https://github.com/docker/compose/releases and replace the latest one with v2.24.3

Comment: This one is good and worked for me but it has some issues that you can solve it easily by reading the issues

Comment: @KasirBarati can you please share the issue So we make this issue free

Comment: Just this part did not work for me: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`. I tried to update the answer but I could not since at that moment the edit queue was full. Thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: @KasirBarati thanks `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`  is used to remove the existing docker-compose  file but in some cases, it is installed in different locations like  `/usr/local/bin/docker/docker-compose` that the reason first command gave error Hope it will help

Comment: TBH no, it was not the case for me.

Answer (score 14):

Do it in three steps. (showing for apt-get installs)

1. Uninstall the last one. e.g. for apt-get installs

> `sudo apt-get remove docker-compose`

2. Install the new one (https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

> `sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

and then

> ```
>  sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
> ```

3. Check your version

> `docker-compose --version`

Comment: Works great, to automatically get the latest version, you could also replace step 2 by: 2a) `COMPOSE_VERSION=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | grep 'tag_name' | cut -d\" -f4)` and then 2b) `sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Comment: one additional step `ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose`

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to install docker-compose on "Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS" but after installing it like this:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

I was getting:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied

and while I was using it with sudo I was getting:

> sudo: docker-compose: command not found

So here's the steps that I took and solved my problem:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: I think that 1-line command should still work from root

Answer (score 6):

On mac (also working on ubuntu):

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/<release-version>/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**NOTE:** write the  as here:
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Answer (score 5):

use this from command line: `sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

### Write down the latest release version

Apply executable permissions to the binary:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Then test version:

```
$ docker-compose --version
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Docker Engine and Docker Compose Plugin

Since Microsoft took over Docker they worked on porting `docker-compose` to their Docker Engine CLI plugins. For future support and updates I would recommend using `docker compose` plugin (Notice the missing dash) which can be install via the `docker-compose-plugin` package. The following instructions assume that you are using Ubuntu as Distro or any Distro thats using `apt` as package manager.

#### Installation Preparations

Update your mirrors:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
```

Make sure the following packages are installed:

```bash
sudo apt-get install \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release
```

After that add the official Docker GPG Key:

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

And finally add the the **stable** repository:

```bash
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

Also make sure Docker Engine and other needed dependencies are installed:

```bash
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

## Installation of `docker compose` plugin

```bash
sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
```

Any future updates of the plugin are easily applied via `apt`.
For further reference take a look at the official installation instructions of [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

Answer (score 3):

If you installed with pip, to upgrade you can just use:

```
 pip install --upgrade docker-compose
```

or as Mariyo states with pip3 explicitly:

```
 pip3 install --upgrade docker-compose
```

Comment: in my case it was `pip3 install --upgrade docker-compose`

Answer (score 3):

Using latest flag in url will redirect you to the latest release of the repo

As OS name is lower case in github's filename, you should convert `uname -s` to lower case using `sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'`.

```sh
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s|sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/')-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the method of installing docker compose version 2.12.x

Update debian package manager

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
```

Then install the plugin manualy

```
 DOCKER_CONFIG=${DOCKER_CONFIG:-$HOME/.docker}
 mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins
 curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.12.2/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

Give permisson of execution of file

```
chmod +x $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

Last test the installation

```
docker compose version
// Docker Composer Version v2.12.2
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of looking at ways to perform this I ended up using `jq`, and hopefully I can expand it to handle other repos beyond Docker-Compose without too much work.

```
# If you have jq installed this will automatically find the latest release binary for your architecture and download it
curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest" | jq --arg PLATFORM_ARCH "$(echo `uname -s`-`uname -m`)" -r '.assets[] | select(.name | endswith($PLATFORM_ARCH)).browser_download_url' | xargs sudo curl -L -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose --url
```

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu desktop 18.04.2, I have the 'local' removed from the path when using the curl command to install the package and it works for me. See above answer by Kshitij.

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
$ sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

$ docker-compose -v
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using Windows + WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04, was necessary only this:

`sudo apt update`

and then:

`sudo apt upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

#### Centos/RHEL

Follow my answer below if you're using **Centos7** with an **x86-64** architecture. This answer is also available in my **github**.

#### Stop Your Docker Containers

I noticed other answers did not talk about stopping your docker containers/images instances before attempting to upgrade **gracefully**. Assumptions are inevitable but can be costly. Onward we go!

#### Options to update Docker-Compose

There are 2 options to upgrade docker-compose if you first downloaded and installed docker-compose using the Curl command.

1. Using Curl, jq package, and Github's direct URL to the docker-compose repository.
2. Using Curl, Sed, and Github's direct URL to the docker-compose repository.

Note: some of the commands below require "sudo" privileges.

#### Demonstration

The script below was saved to a file called "update_docker_compose.sh". You need to give this file executable permissions.

Like so:

```
chmod +x update_docker_compose.sh
```

"docker_docker_compose.sh" file content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# author: fullarray (stackoverflow user)
# Contribution shared on: stackoverflow.com
# Contribution also available on: github.com
# date: 06112022

# Stop current docker container running
docker stop containerID

# Remove current docker network running
docker rm containerID

# Remove image of target application(s)
docker image rm imageID

# Delete either dangling (unatagged images) docker containers or images or network
docker system prune -f

# This step depends on the jq package. 
# Uncomment jq package installation command below if using Centos7 x86-64.
# sudo yum install jq

# Declare variable to get latest version of docker-compose from github repository
compose_version=$(curl https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | jq .name -r)

# Declare variable to target installation directory
target_install_dir='/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'

# Get OS and build (assumes Linux Centos7 and x86_64)
get_local_os_build=$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)

# Execute curl command to carry download and installation operation
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$compose_version/docker-compose-$get_local_os_build -o $target_install_dir

# Use chmod to modify permissions to target installation directory (to make it executable)
chmod +x $target_install_dir

# Print docker-compose version to terminal to verify upgrade
$(docker-compose --version)
```

#### Edit the script with variables specific to your environment

The script above has a few variables you need to edit with values specific to your docker environment. For instance, you need to replace **container ID** and **image ID** with the values that the following commands output.

```
docker ps
```

and

```
docker images output
```

Once you finalize creating the file (including the edits). Switch to the directory that contains the file. For example, if you created the file in /home/username/script/update_docker_compose.sh

```
cd /home/username/script
```

Last, run the script by executing the following

```
./update_docker_compose.sh
```

#### Option 2

Create a script file name "update_docker_compose.sh"

Edit the file and add the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# author: fullarray (stackoverflow user)
# Contribution shared on: stackoverflow.com
# Contribution also available on: github.com
# date: 06112022

# Stop current docker container running
docker stop containerID

# Remove current docker network running
docker rm containerID

# Remove image of target application(s)
docker image rm imageID

# Delete either dangling (unatagged images) docker containers or images or network
docker system prune -f

# Declare variable to target installation directory
target_install_dir='/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'

# Get OS and build (assumes Linux Centos7 and x86_64)
get_local_os_build=$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)

# Execute curl and sed command to carry out download and installation operation
# compose_latest_version=$(curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/`curl -fsSLI -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest | sed 's#.*tag/##g' && echo`/docker-compose-$get_local_os_build") -o $target_install_dir

# Use chmod to modify permissions to target installation directory (to make it executable)
chmod +x $target_install_dir

# Print docker-compose version to terminal to verify upgrade
$(docker-compose --version)
```

#### Edit the script with variables specific to your environment

The script above also has a few variables you need to edit with values specific to your docker environment. For instance, you need to replace **container ID** and **image ID** with the values that the following commands output.

```
docker ps
```

and

```
docker images output
```

Once you finalize creating the file (including the edits). Switch to the directory that contains the file. For example, if you created the file in /home/username/script/update_docker_compose.sh

```
cd /home/username/script
```

Last, run the script by executing the following

```
./update_docker_compose.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have homebrew you can also install via `brew`

```
$ brew install docker-compose
```

This is a good way to install on a Mac OS system

Answer (score -1):

Most of these solutions are outdated or make you install old version.
To install the latest

```sh
sudo apt  install jq

DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=$(curl --silent https://api.github.com/repos/docker/compose/releases/latest | jq .name -r)

sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, my case was pretty weird. I am using wsl2, and Docker Desktop (Windows 11). I stop getting this error after rename the folder "docker" to "config-dev-server" and update de Dockerfile like this this:

```
COPY ./docker/apache/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

to

```
COPY ./config-dev-server/apache/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Answer (score -2):

With a newer Docker Desktop for Mac 3.3.0, you don't need to install Docker Compose as a seperate package. Docker Compose comes as a first class citizen installed with Docker by default. Check out the below CLI:

```
docker compose version
Docker Compose version 2.0.0-beta.1%
```