# Docker: b'json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field LogConfig.Config of type string'

Tags: json, docker, docker-compose

I configured my application in docker compose to use rotating logs, following the in the following site:
https://medium.com/@Quigley_Ja/rotating-docker-logs-keeping-your-overlay-folder-small-40cfa2155412

```
my-app:
image: my-app:latest
logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
        max-file: 5
        max-size: 10m
```

But when I run the program now it cannot start with the following error:
b'json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field LogConfig.Config of type string'

Answer (score 52):

Turns out I had to put " " around the values:

```
my-app:
image: my-app:latest
logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
        max-file: "5"
        max-size: "10m"
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has this problem, just update composer to latest version.
[How to upgrade docker-compose to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49839172/16513528)

Comment: Was wondering why I started getting this error.. Turned out I've been always using "docker compose" and mistyped as "docker-compose".

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number 5 to string:

```
my-app:
  image: my-app:latest
  logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
      max-file: "5"
      max-size: 10m
```