# Docker-compose - facing error while starting container after adding logging option

Tags: logging, docker-compose

We have Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f. It is running fine without logging options in docker-compose.yml but when we specify the logging options and then start docker-compose, it throws an error
"ERROR: for   Cannot create container for service : json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field LogConfig.HostConfig.LogConfig.Config of type string"

This is the entry in docker-compose.yml under that service -

```
logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
            max-file: 5
            max-size: 10m
```

Please let me know what might be wrong with our configuration. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

Turned out that I had to specify max-file as string. It was already asked by someone 4 years ago, who found the answer himself.
[Docker: b'json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field LogConfig.Config of type string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939953/docker-bjson-cannot-unmarshal-number-into-go-struct-field-logconfig-config-of)

```
logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
            max-file: "5"
            max-size: 10m
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Heya, it just helped me!  I had a push to prod go wrong, and found this via a Google search, so thank you!