# Installing docker-compose v2.1.1 in Ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to install docker-compose v2.1.1 in Ubuntu through the command line (currently on 1.29.2)

I'm using the instructions from the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose

Running the command

`sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.1.1./docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` downloads the version 2.1.1 and I apply it with  `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

After this the `docker-compose --version` still shows 1.29.2 though

Is the process to install v2.1.1 any different or am I missing something?

Comment: at first you must delete the last docker-compose `which docker-compose`
 remove it and go on

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49839172/14916414 possible duplicate?

Comment: Thank you, that looks like the solution I'm looking for. Closing thread